# Generate image position based on a draggable surface with rotation

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd, image-resizing

Working with a `div` box with static dimensions, I load an image of larger or smaller dimensions than the `div` so I am able to rotate, change size, and move the image inside that `div`.

I am accomplishing this via css 3 for the rotate functionality, jquery ui for the moving functionality.

Upon interacting with the image, I want to generate the image with the new position, angle and size.  So, I send to the server the position of the image, the angle of the rotation and the new size.
On server I generate a image that has the width and height of the `div`.
The problem is when I have a larger image and I change his position, I am unable to generate the same on server.

Here is my algorithm for generating the new image that have the size and width of the `div` box (670/465):

```
$imgFace = WideImage::load($src);
$newImage = $imgFace->resize($width, $height)->rotate($angle); // resize the image and rotate to $angle
$rotW = $newImage->getWidth();
$rotH = $newImage->getHeight();
$dx = $rotW - $width;
$dy = $rotH - $height;   
if($width < 670 && $height < 465) // if the image is smaller than the div box
{
   $newImage->copyTo($img, $left, $top); // left and top are values from css after I move the image
} else { // if is larger
   $crop_x = $dx/2 + $left;
   $crop_y = $dy/2 + $top;
   $newImageCroped = $newImage->crop($crop_x, $crop_y,670,465);
   $newImageCroped->copyTo($img, $leftB, $topB);
}
```

In short, I run into issues in the following scenarios:

- When the image is taller than the `div` box and I move it (only a part of it is in the `div`)
- When the image is rotated and he have only a part of it in `div`.

Comment: Is this so hard than nobody know an answer ? :)